# pointed homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous map of topological spaces $X \to Y$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are CW complexes. Let $X_+$ be the following space: take $X$ and attach a 0-cell (disjointly). Same for $Y_+$. Suppose the induced map $X_+ \to Y_+$ is a weak homotopy equivalence of pointed spaces. Does this mean that $f$ was a weak homotopy equivalence?

I'm getting confused on the definitions. If I have a random WHE $X_+ \to Y_+$, then it's definitely not true, but I couldn't think of a counterexample when the WHE is induced by a continuous map of unbased spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The homotopy groups depend on the base point and they only depend on the path component this base point belongs to. If you choose base points in $X$ and $Y$, then the homotopy groups of $X_+$ and $Y_+$ with respect to this base point are the same as for $X$ and $Y$ because the added point belongs to another path component. In particular $f$ induces the same map between homotopy groups of $X_+$ and $Y_+$ as it does for those of $X$ and $Y$ and thus is again a weak homotopy equivalence.